# Magical floating hats

Tags: bug, ios-app, winter-bash-2015

On user profile page: Hats appear correctly positioned ...

[image]

until the page is scrolled...

[image]

- App Version: 1.4.1
- Device: iPhone 6
- OS Version: Version 9.1 (Build 13B143)